# Explore which files are heavily used in the system

Tags: performance, ubuntu, file-io, load

I'm using ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

`atopsar -d 30` - shows that one of hard drive (sda) in the system is heavily used. This hard drive serves only mysql database. The most frequently used DBs where relocated to another hard drives (sdb, sdd) via symbolic links. Now `atopsar` shows nearly same load for `sda` and under 5% load to other HDDs.

Is there a way to know which files are heavily used on HDD?

Can it be that mysql InnoDB log files (ib_logfile) are fragmented? And therefore `atopsar` show such big load (50%-70%). What can be done in that case?

There are some output from `atopsar -d 30`:

```
08:52:47  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
08:53:17  sda             63%    0.0     0.0    50.2    14.6   1.1  12.57 ms
          sdb              5%    0.0     0.0     9.4    19.8   4.2   5.81 ms
          sdd              2%    0.0     0.0     3.7    18.9   1.4   5.82 ms
08:53:47  sda             60%    0.0    16.0    48.1    15.7   1.0  12.55 ms
          sdb              5%    0.0     0.0     6.9    17.5   4.6   7.35 ms
          sdd              2%    0.0     0.0     4.7    24.9   1.4   4.06 ms
08:54:17  sda             38%    0.5    16.0    30.6    15.6   1.2  12.25 ms
          sdb              3%    0.0     0.0     5.6    18.3   3.3   5.50 ms
          sdd              2%    0.0     0.0     3.3    19.2   1.1   4.86 ms
08:54:47  sda             53%    0.0     0.0    42.5    16.5   1.1  12.37 ms
          sdb              6%    0.0     0.0     8.7    21.0   5.8   6.37 ms
          sdd              2%    0.0     0.0     3.1    23.1   1.3   5.68 ms
08:55:17  sda             51%    0.0     4.0    42.7    16.9   1.1  11.94 ms
          sdb              5%    0.0     0.0     9.4    20.5   5.0   5.51 ms
          sdd              1%    0.0     0.0     1.5    17.6   1.1   7.73 ms
08:55:47  sda             52%    0.0     0.0    40.6    14.5   1.0  12.85 ms
          sdb              5%    0.0     0.0     6.8    19.5   5.4   6.66 ms
          sdd              2%    0.0     0.0     4.3    31.3   1.3   4.78 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the most heavily used files in the system please use: `sudo pt-ioprofile -cell sizes`
Example of output:

```
     total      pread       read     pwrite      fsync      lseek filename
  10862592          0          0   10862592          0          0 /var/mysqldata/mysql/ibdata1
    827392          0          0     827392          0          0 /var/mysqllog/mysql/ib_logfile0
... (other trivial I/O records truncated)
```

Got it from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/innodb-high-disk-write-i-o-on-ibdata1-file-and-ib-logfile0

Please be aware that by default Percona toolkit attaches only to mysqld. And to find out most heavily used file you have to run it to all processes that might create such load. In my case I was definitely sure that it's mysql server, so it's enough for me.

Please read http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-ioprofile.html before you use it.

Answer (score 6):

There is `sysdig` tool which allow you to see system-wide activities just like `strace` does for single process: http://www.sysdig.org/

There are examples for Disk usage info: https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig%20Examples#disk-io

> See the top processes in terms of disk bandwidth usage

```
sysdig -c topprocs_file
```

> See the top files in terms of read+write bytes

```
sysdig -c topfiles_bytes
```

> Print the top files that apache has been reading from or writing to

```
sysdig -c topfiles_bytes proc.name=httpd
```

> See the top directories in terms of R+W disk activity

```
sysdig -c fdbytes_by fd.directory "fd.type=file"
```

> See the top files in terms of R+W disk activity in the /tmp directory
>       sysdig -c fdbytes_by fd.filename "fd.directory=/tmp/"
>
> Observe the I/O activity on all the files named 'passwd'

```
sysdig -A -c echo_fds "fd.filename=passwd"
```

Sysdig is modern and convenient tool. For older Linuxes is it possible to get similar information using [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap): http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2014/05/systemtap-as-a-system-wide-strace-tool.html

PS Thanks to habrahabr.ru with this post about Sysdig http://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/222839/

PPS Brendan D. Gregg created this picture "A quick tour of many tools..." for his [Linux Performance page](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html):

[image: Brendan D. Gregg about linux performance and tracing]

Comment: It's not available in Ubuntu repositories

Comment: http://www.sysdig.org/install/ - the sysdig installer supports ubuntu from 10.04: `curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.draios.com/stable/install-sysdig | sudo bash`

Comment: Sure I read that it's possible and easy to install it on ubuntu. But to be honest I do not completely trust soft that is not in the repository. Specially when it comes to near production server. So therefore I prefer percona tool described by me.

Comment: percona tool is based on strace (ptrace), so I would not run it on production server for long time too. Sysdig (and perf too) is new tool and has less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try investigating with

```
dstat --top-bio
```

it will give you processes that use most of IO.
In linux you have /proc/diskstats - it gives only block device level stats. 
I have never seen a mechanism to determine which file is busy in linux.